# Is "giving a f**k" a valid opposite of "not giving a f**k"?

Tags: phrases, antonyms

When *"I don't give a f..k"* means *"I don't care"* does *"I give a f..k"* mean the opposite (which would be *"I **do** care"*)?

Additionally, would the question *"If they'd give a f..k"* mean *"If they'd care?"* Would this be a valid question and generally understood?

Comment: Have you ever heard anyone say it in the affirmative ?

Comment: It could be. For example: "Why should I give a f--k?" would mean the same as  "Why should I care?". But saying "I give a f--*k* about the environment" is not idiomatic. Nor is your added sentence, I think - unless it came in a context of responding to the negative.

Comment: Added the question where I used it which lead to the question if there's even an opposite of not giving a f..k.

Comment: I can't back this up, so won't make it an answer yet, but it seems to me that the idea behind these idioms is that the *damn*, *fuck* or *shit* is meant to suggest something minuscule; that is, *I don't **even** give a damn [which is the least I could give]*, or less vulgarly, *this isn't worth a hill of beans.*  With that last idiom, it's very clear that it can't be stated in the affirmative: *It is worth a hill of beans* doesn't make any sense. I think it's the same with these other idioms. The affirmative version would mean *I **do** care a minuscule amount*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! A very good question indeed...

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

There are plenty of authors and publications which use the expression in the affirmative (if you count other substitutes to `fuck`, like `shit` or `damn`, which essentially mean the same thing). Some examples:

[This quote](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/quotes/qt2218735) from the movie Guardians of the Galaxy:

> Peter Quill: .. And you think life takes more than it gives, but not today. Today it's giving
> us something. It is giving us a chance.
>
> Rocket Raccoon: To do what?
>
> Peter Quill: *To give a shit.* And I am not gonna stand by and watch as
> billions of lives are being wiped out.

Or this character from John Le Carre's "The Constant Garderner", who is [described](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2005/oct/06/fiction.johnlecarre) as 'The Angel Who Gave a Damn'.

> Cornwell has written eulogies to her work and dedicated The Constant Gardener to her: "For Yvette Pierpaoli, who lived and died giving a damn." Tessa, too, gives a damn, but only after her death does her husband realise the value of his dead wife's passion for justice.

Leslie Howard had a [documentary](http://www.tcm.com/this-month/article/1402035%7C0/Leslie-Howard-The-Man-Who-Gave-a-Damn.html) named after this phrase:

> LESLIE HOWARD: THE MAN WHO GAVE A DAMN
>
> Anyone who knew Leslie Howard, either by reputation or in person, knew he was something rarely seen in the entertainment industry: A man of principle.

Admittedly, this is almost certainly meant to be a play on the famous line from "Gone With the Wind", which is in the negative.

---

As for your question about interrogatory sentences, they go hand-in-hand with negative sentences and that usage is actually very common. ("Who gives a shit?" is widely used to mean "Who cares?") In fact, "Who doesn't give a shit?" (= everyone cares) would be the rarer sentence in my opinion.

Comment: Note that this use is rare and jocular. It's making a joke out of a literal interpretation of the idiom.

Comment: Sure, the affirmative is used Le Carré is a master irony-maker. [my coinage]

Comment: But maybe “give a shit” (=affirmative, “to care”) is different than “give a fuck” (=affirmative, meaning?)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr *Q1: No, it isn’t. Q2: yes, it would.*

Negative [polarity items](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) can be quirky grammatically.

Removing “not” doesn’t automatically produce a natural antonym. This is especially so when the ‘negated’ form (such as with your example) represents an extreme of a spectrum of possibilities and the non-negated form doesn’t represent the other extreme.

Sometimes, due to the peculiarities of English grammar - particularly with negative-polarity elements - removing *not* (as a naive reversal of the negation) reduces the sentence to an ungrammatical mess.

Here’s a more polite example:

- I do not care at all.

Removing *not* leaves something ungrammatical:

- I do care (*) *at all*.

We’d need to also remove “at all” to reverse the negation. However, while this is easy to do when the negative polarity elements are separable from the main part of the sentence, it isn’t as easy to do when they are enmeshed, as they are in your example.

Here’s another example, closer to yours in that it doesn’t have trailing detritus:

- He will not [give two hoots about it](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+two+hoots).

This uses slang to say that he doesn’t care about it at all.

Removing *not* leaves something grammatical but not idiomatic, as is the case with your example:

- He (*) will give two hoots about it.

At best, we can parse this to mean he cares a little about it, but really, the sentence is unidiomatic.

These can all be considered negative polarity items

The answer to the question in your title is “No”.

The answer to your trailing question is, on the other hand, “yes”. The conditional changes something that might objectively be termed *bland sentiment* to produce a direct antonym (complete disregard to strongly caring, rather than a casual interest). “If he would give two hoots about it ....” conveys the sense that “he” doesn’t care, strongly suggesting that he *should* care.

Comment: This is true, as well. I don't care at all. I do care a lot.

Comment: If you want to show that “give a fuck” is a negative polarity item, it would be helpful to run the whole battery of tests.

Comment: @RichardZ By “negative polarity elements”, my first reference in this answer was to my own example - specifically, the words “at all”. The second reference (now removed) might have been a misuse of the term.

Comment: No, I mean the reference to negative polarity items (npi) is probably the right answer to this question so you might want to expand on this. NPIs are good after long distance negation (“Nobody intended to say that I would give a fuck” seems ok) after “without”. (“Without giving a fuck” seems ok too), in question, if-clauses etc. That’s what I meant by “battery of tests”.

Comment: Your first example made me wonder - you're removing the *not*, but the *at all* is also part of the negation. I would say you'd need to turn both into a positive, ending up with (for example) *I do care a lot*, which is actually OK.

Comment: @microenzo The issue is that negative polarity items can get weird when naively un-negated. It’s very obvious with my first example because elements associated with the negation are easily separable from the meat of the sentence. In the OP’s example, the negative elements are enmeshed. Removing just the “not” from my first example demonstrates something of the difficulty with in-negating NPIs.